# What are the differences between Fterolaka and Kelara locations of the Parnassos Ski Center?

Tags: automobiles, greece, skiing

The Parnassos Ski Center seems to have more than one locations for skiing. In particular it seems to have at least two separate locations, Fterolaka and Kelaria. 
Are they indeed separate locations? They seem close on the map.
Do they both offer rental skis and other ski equipment?
Is perhaps one location specific to skis and the other specific for snowboard? 
Is there parking in both locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer, my Greek is non-existant.

Have a look at the web site : https://parnassos-ski.gr/  (or better https://parnassos-ski.gr/map_info/)

There is a map with the different areas; the resort has two bases.

There are 2 parking areas.

the one on the left side, at 1650m altitude only has tickets. at altitude 1850 , there seems to be rental (if I can read the image correctly), but no parking.

The one on the right side at altitude 1750, there is parking and rentals and other amenities. This seems to be main base; this would be where I would go.